To 'cd' by altering only the middle part of the path
In Zsh, to cd from ~/foo/bar/aaa/bbb/ccc to ~/foo/bar/zzz/bbb/ccc, I can type cd aaa zzz, and that's it. I have carefully read the Fish cd man page, but I still cannot figure out: is the same thing possible there?

It's not possible, the documentation is clear on that, /usr/share/doc/fish/cmds/cd.html on most systems.

cd [DIRECTORY]


doesn't leave room for interpretation; there's zero or one argument to cd.
You could of course write your own shell function, named cd, that counts the number of arguments it gets, if they're < 2 just command cd $argv[1]; else gets the current pwd, replaces the $argv[1] component with $argv[2] and command cd to the result.
Note that you probably shouldn't do that, however. Fish is a bit … strange in that it has no notion of shell aliases, i.e., you cannot have something that only works in interactive mode. So, from there on, every time a fish shell script does cd, it would execute your own shell function instead, and that can simply take a lot of time for one of the operations that are most common in shell scripts!
